# iPad crash with Foundation

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

Our website crashes on iPad when running with foundation css, and not crashes when running without foundation css.

Scenario:
Playing with the page scroll up and down few times (scrolling is laggy). At some point the page will be refreshed and a browser error message appears on the top of the page. This scenario is not consistent and the crash may occur after a random period of time or random number of scroll actions.

What we have tried:
We removed the webkit backface rules from the css, as we found it in some forums, it didn't solve our crash. 
Tried upgrading to foundation 5.5.2 - also didn't help.

Environment:
iOS - 8.4
iPad Retina
Safari and Chrome
Foundation 5.5.0

Thanks